# Relationship with sister that has a specific class

Tags: css

Not sure if this is doable in `css` but what I was wanting to do is

Say, you have your `html` structure like below:-

```
<h4>Title <span class="specific"> text </span> </h4>
<div>
    <p> This is some text. </p>
</div>
```

Now, I want to style the `div p` elements but I want to use `h4 span.specific` as a relation for `div p` element.

Using parenthesis, it might look like this. `(h4 span.specific) ~ (div p)`

Just wanted to know if this can be done with only CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, selectors consists of relations between single elements (+ pseudo-classes). You would like to have relations between selectors, which isn't possible as today and won't be in CSS4.

The problem is that if you traversed down in the DOM tree using CSS, there's simply no way to traverse up (apart from the *Determining the subject of a selector* selector `!`), so one cannot create such relation.

In order to fix this you must be able to recognize the `h4 > span.specific` without looking at the `span`, for example apply the class on the `h4` instead.

#### References:

- http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#overview
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors

Comment: Looks like you're the only one who understood what I was trying to say. Thanks. I'll try to find some other ways. This helps.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is really powerful and will help you to do so.

Instead of (h4 span.specific) ~ (div p), use

```
h4 > span.specific + div > p
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:

you cannot specify span.specific, however you can say a p inside a div followed by an h4, i.e

```
h4 + div > p.
```

Apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis is not valid CSS selector operator.

The sequence of selectors and combinators is read from right to left.

```
<h4 class="specificParent">Title <span class="specific"> text </span> </h4>
<div>
    <p> This is some text. </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
h4.specificParent~div>p {
    background-color: red;
 }
```

It interprets the above statement as

Select an p element
that has parent div
that is sibling of h4 which has specificParent class

Please find the working demo here: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fdqdD/24/)

Comment: I was just trying to get my point across by introducing parenthesis.

Comment: You're also missing my point by not having "specific" class in the child element on your css. Sorry but this was a bit tricky to explain.

Answer (score 0):

you can only achieve this by this

i cant find any other solution for this

**http://jsfiddle.net/8QBkz/**

```
h4 ~ div p{
   color:green 

}
```

Comment: That would mean me changing color of all the p element in the div sibling with h4 as sister selector. I wanted only those selector that has h4 as a sister selector that has sibling with specific class.

    h4 > span.specific

Comment: sorry tgere is no parent selector in css